# Move selection to the end on narrowed element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cordova, mobile-safari, ios6.1

I'm writing an app in phonegap with a specific 'zoom-in' effect when clicking on an input element (everything but the input hides and custom typeahead suggestions are shown). The view is written using backbone.js and i'm entering the 'zoomed-in' mode on focus:

```
events: {
            'focus .search': 'startSearch',
}
```

In my `startSearch` method i'm doing all the logic to immitate the `zoom-in` effect.

```
    _moveCursorToEnd: function(element) {
        var val_len = element.value.length;
        element.scrollLeft = val_len * 9;
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.selectionStart = val_len;
        }, 1);
    },

    startSearch: function() {
        window.navbar.hide();
        this.$input.addClass('search-input-small');
        this.$cancel.show();

        var el = this.$input[0];
        this._moveCursorToEnd(el);

    },
```

The `search-input-small` makes the input smaller.

The `setTimeout` in `_moveCursorToEnd` is required because the effect doesn't work otherwise. The issue is that despite `setTimeout` having 1msec, it looks like a second cause inconvenient cursor move.

Is there any way to move the cursor to the end that would work on Safari Mobile 6 (iOS 6+) without the ugly delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up changing the event from `focus` to `click` and using similar code as mentioned above so that it works. Seems like the selection from a click that focused the text edit is applied after `focus` handler and before `click` handler.